# Question regarding product topology

Tags: general-topology

In **James.E.Munkres** in the definition of product topology it's written that

$\pi_{\beta}:\sqcap_{\alpha\in J} X_{\alpha}\rightarrow X_{\beta}$

Let $S_{\beta}$ denotes the collection of {$\pi^{-1}_{\beta}(U_{\beta})|U_{\beta}$ is open in $X_{\beta}$}. Let S denotes the union of the collection $S=\cup_{\beta\in J} S _{\beta}$. The topology generated by the subbasis$S$ is called **product topology**. Now from  the definition it seems to me that there exists a unique set from each $X_{\beta}$ that is $X_{\beta}$ itself. As the union  of element of the subbasis equals to the set.

But after that when they are considering the basis $\beta$ that $S$ generates. Then they are telling that if we intersect two elements belonging to the same set we do not get anything new. As $\pi^{-1}(U_{\beta})\cap \pi^{-1}(V_{\beta})=\pi^{-1}_{\beta}(U_{\beta}\cap V_{\beta})$ but according to previous deduction there shouldn't be anyy set other than $X_{\beta}$. I am confused about this. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: I mean consider consider the union $S_{\beta}$. It is basically cartesian product of all the other $X_{\alpha}$ with union of open sets of {X_\beta}. As $S$ is a subbasis then the union should be equal to $\sqcap_{\alpha\in J} X_{\alpha}$

Comment: Note that $S=\cup_{\beta\in J}S_\beta$ means constructing a set whose elements are all of the elements in all of the $S_\beta$. It does not mean taking the union of all of the elements in all of the $S_\beta$. $S$ is a set of sets.

Comment: That means $S=\sqcap_{\alpha\in J} X_{\alpha}$. Is'nt it??

Comment: Anyone??? I am kind of stuck

Comment: No S is not the product  of X's (written as square without bottom edge).  It is a collection of sets of the form (pi_j)^-1(U) for j in J and U within X_ j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recollection (as I don't have my copy of that text handy), is the the essential difference between the box and product topologies is only relevant for infinite collections of topological spaces (e.g. $J$ being an infinite index set). In this case the difference is that the for the product topology, only finitely many of the factor projections go to a proper (open) subset of the relevant factor space (the specific $X_{\alpha}$) whereas, for the box topology, that may happen for infinitely many of the factors.

$S$ is the subbasis for the product topology, which is being defined on $\Pi_{\alpha\in J}X_{\alpha}$. The way this construction is carried out is as follows:

Chose an arbitrary $\beta\in J$.

For the factor, $X_{\beta}$, we construct the obvious factor projection map: $\pi_{\beta}:\Pi_{\alpha\in J}X_{\alpha}\rightarrow X_{\beta}$, which takes a each point in the product space, and projects down to the factor by ignoring the 'other coordinates' (For $\mathbb{R}^3$, for example, the projection map for the '$x$' variable would take $(x,y,z)$ to $x$, and the projection map for $y$ would take $(x,y,z)$ to $y$, etc.)

We take each $U_{\beta}$ open in $X_{\beta}$, We take it's pre-image under the projection map $\pi_{\beta}$, which is a set that looks like: $U_{\beta}\times\Pi_{\alpha\in J,\alpha\neq\beta}X_{\alpha}$ (where for notational convenience I've reordered the product so that $\beta$ is first). Using the $\mathbb{R}^3$ example, the open interval $(0,1)$ in the $x$ variable would be pre-imaged to a prism-like shape, which would have $x\in(0,1)$ and $y$ and $z$ free (meaning they are allowed to take any value). $S_{\beta}$ is then the collection of open sets that we get for our product space via this construction for the given $\beta$.

The above is done for every $\beta\in J$. We take the union of all of the collections, $S_{\beta}$ obtained this way, and thereby construct $S$, which is to be our subbasis for our topology.

The full collection of open sets for the topology of the product space can be derived from this subbasis via the usual methods: First take every possible intersection of *finitely many* subbasis elements. Then, from this expanded collection (which is actually a basis for the topology in question), we take every possible union of any amount of sets from this collection.

In the box topology, you can have open sets in the product that look like:
$\Pi_{\alpha\in J}U_{\alpha}$ where all the $U_{\alpha}$'s are proper (open) subsets of their respective factors, unlike in the product topology, where for only finitely many of the $\alpha$'s may it be the case that $U_{\alpha}$ isn't the entirety of $X_{\alpha}$.